# What would the following code block do?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

Recently I came across this code in solidity:

```
fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
```

I know what happens till a value is assigned to the result variable but can't figure out what the "if block" is doing.

I tried to create a similar program in remix IDE and look for this code in the docs and blogs but no luck. [Here is the full code](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493) .

I'm sorry if this is dumb but I just started solidity. So if anyone was kind enough to explain about how can I tackle these sorts of situations in future I would be extra grateful.

Comment: This is just a dummy into which you can insert the processing of the results.

Comment: So it is basically the "pass" keyword in python for solidity?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it